# Excepcion InputMismatchException

Tags: java

Porque este trozo de código me tira un error:

```
package com.gmail.brunodiazmartin5;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MiClase {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    double d = sc.nextDouble(); //Excepcion si introduzco 452.65487
                                //java.util.InputMismatchException

    double d2 = 452.65487; //Y esto que es el mismo valor no da error
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mirando [la documentación](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_nextdouble.htm) veo que el metodo `nextDouble` se puede aplicar a `Scanner`'s pero el problema es que si el contenido no encaja con la regex que valida si es o no `double`, el resultado es la excepcion de  `InputMismatchException`.

Si especificas el `locale` con `sc.useLocale(Locale.US);` entonces tu variable `sc` si puede usar `nextDouble` al llevar punto y no coma.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
sc.useLocale(Locale.US);
double d = sc.nextDouble();
```