# InputMismatchException

Tags: java

Cómo puedo solucionar esto? en la imagen solo está proporcionado el error en la consola

cómo puedo solucionar este error?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido. Por favor pon el código y el error como texto. Respecto al error, `Scanner` divide la entrada en *tokens*. Normalmente son palabras o están separadas por espacio en blanco. Con `next` estarías obteniendo una sola palabra y no la línea completa.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Excepcion InputMismatchException](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/108554/excepcion-inputmismatchexception)